# Deploy Angular project to Cordova - Android Studio

Tags: angular, cordova, android-studio

Recently I did build an Angular project and built it. Now I need to move this built content to a Cordova application. As I'm using Angular if I directly access some URLs like http://localhost/login?returnUrl=%2Fspaces I get a 404 error on Apache servers. To avoid this, I did add the following code to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Is there a way that I can do the same for the Cordova project. I did add the .htaccess file to the project and build it for Android and run it on Android Studio Emulator and getting the following error:

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8GpQ.png)

Is there any alternative way to work this code for Cordova application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Cordova seems to have problems with .htaccess files. I'm searching a way for configuring the URLs within the Cordova Browser platform and wasn't able to find one.

Try to use Ionic if possible, they seem to support the .htaccess: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-build-for-browser/151518